# Next js installation in windows 7 os

Tags: windows, next.js, version

**How to use Next js in windows 7**
I am using windows 7 os. In windows 7 os i have installed nodejs of version 17 and npm(*By using releases zip files and changing some environment in system*). After this i am able to use react but when I move on to use **Nextjs** it will require nodejs of version 18.1 or later but I am not able to upgrade nodejs more, due to compatibly issues so I am looking for a way to use next js in windows 7?

how to accomplish this?

I have tried different previous version of nextjs and but when I tried to run development sever it not worked